# How to divide a live stream coming from a camera into many 60-second video clips in mp4 format with ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, split, mp4, live-streaming

Using the following code:

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -rtbufsize 1000M -i video = "Game Capture HD60 S (Video) (# 01)" -codec copy -map 0 -f segment -segment_time 60 -reset_timestamps 1 "C: \ Program Files (x86) \ ffmpeg \ test \ clips \ testfile_piece_% 02d.mp4 "
```

I have the following problem:

> "Could not find tag for codec rawvideo in stream # 0, codec not
> currently supported in container Could not write header for output
> file # 0 (incorrect codec parameters?): Invalid argument"

How can I fix it?

Thank you

Comment: Did you try using normal paths instead of paths with strange spaces? **(1)** Why is it `C: \ Program Files (x86) \` instead of the correctly expected `C:\Program Files (x86)\` ? **(2)** Why `-i video =` and what happens if you instead use an actual file name like `-i myFile.mp4 -codec copy ...etc`?

Comment: MP4s don't support raw video, MOVs do.

Answer (score 0):

## Raw video

You are using `-codec copy` which enables [stream copy](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) mode. dshow outputs uncompressed raw video. MP4 does not support raw video.

**You probably don't want raw video.** It makes huge files and your player may not play it.

If you want raw video change output to MOV, Matroska (`.mkv`), or perhaps AVI (AVI does not support all raw video pixel formats).

## Choose an encoder

Because you are outputting to MP4 you probably want H.264 or H.265/HEVC video instead of raw video.

Replace `-codec copy` with `-c:v libx264` or `-c:v libx265`.

Or omit `-codec copy` and it will use the default encoder for MP4, which will almost certainly be libx264 (it depends on your `ffmpeg` configuration: see `ffmpeg -h muxer=mp4`).

So your command may look like:

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -rtbufsize 1000M -i video="Game Capture HD60 S (Video) (# 01)" -c:v libx264 -map 0 -f segment -segment_time 60 -reset_timestamps 1 "C:\Program Files (x86)\ffmpeg\test\clips\testfile_piece_%02d.mp4"
```